# Spring Struts Hibernate Maven Project Error

Tags: hibernate, spring, maven, struts

I want to create a Spring Struts Hibernate web app using Maven. My porject POM.xml

```
*<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">*
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>satunol</groupId>
 <artifactId>PMS</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>PMS Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.grizzly</groupId>
  <artifactId>grizzly-servlet-webserver</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.36</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>plexus-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- jUnit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Struts 2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>

<!-- MySQL database driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring framework --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Struts 2 + Spring plugins -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.7.ga</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate core library dependency start -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Hibernate core library dependency end -->

<!-- Hibernate query library dependency start -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Hibernate query library dependency end -->


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>PMS</finalName>
  </build>
 </project>
```

But i got error like this.,

- Failure to transfer org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:1.2 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:1.2 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): No route to host: no further information to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.2/plexus-archiver-1.2.jar
- Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0
- Missing artifact javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B

How can i resolve this.,thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maven is unable to reach a repository.  Are you working in a secure network - say at a place of work?  If so and you have a proxy server specify it in the [settings file](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies).

Comment: What Maven goal/phase did you invoke to get the error?  I was able to  run `mvn clean` with your **exact** POM (minus the two asterisks on the first line) with no error.

Comment: same with you, when i run mvn clean from cmd in my project.,BUILD SUCCESS. But, when i see my pom.xml in Eclipse, it has 3 error which i have mention above, and when i try to open http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.2/plexus-archiver-1.2.jar from my browser.,there is no problem. My Elcipse didn't use proxy. It use 'native' connection in network connection setting.

Comment: oh.,if the wireless where i connected use a password, is it must be setup to in the file setting.xml? or we just setup the file setting.xml if the wireless using proxy? thank you..